# Escaping LaTeX control symbols in Hmisc::latex

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

I have a data frame in R which unfortunately has strings in it containing dollar signs. When the function `latex()` from the package [`Hmisc`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) converts this data frame to a LaTeX table, the dollar signs are not escaped. This renders the LaTeX uncompilable. Is there a way within `Hmisc` to escape dollar signs when formatting values from a data frame?

I can't run search and replace over all dollar signs afterwards either, because the `Hmisc` itself adds dollar signs for the empty cells.

Minimal example:

```
> latex("test$test",file="")
# returns:
\begin{table}[!tbp]
% [...]
test$test\tabularnewline
% [...]
\end{table}

# should return:
\begin{table}[!tbp]
% [...]
test\$test\tabularnewline
% [...]
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the `latexTranslate` function, from `Hmisc` :

```
R> latexTranslate("3%")
[1] "3\\%"
```

Comment: Looks useful, thanks. Can this be integrated with `latex` though? Or only via `sapply` beforehand?

Comment: You can use `latex(latexTranslate("test$test"))` for example. Or maybe I didn't understand your question ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to apply it to the cells of a data frame, when calling `latex(df)`. But I guess `latex(as.data.frame(sapply(df,latexTranslate)))` will do.