# R - Handling cut intervals of form [x,y] in tables when converting to LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pdflatex

I'm working on a document in R, with knitr to pdflatex and am using the extended version of `toLatex` from memisc.

When I'm producing a table with cut intervals however, the square brackets are not sanitised and the pdflatex job errors because of the existence of `[`.

I tried putting `sanitize=TRUE` in the knitr chunk code, but this only works for tikz.

Previously, I have used gsub and replaced the string in the R object itself which is rather inelegant.  I'm hoping someone could point me in the direction of a nuance of memisc or knitr that I'm missing or another function/method that would easily handle latex special characters.

Example

```
library("memisc")
library("Hmisc")
example<-data.frame(cbind(x=1:100,y=1:100))
example$x<-cut2(example$x,m=20)
toLatex(example)
```

**UPDATE**

Searching SO I found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771714/escaping-latex-control-symbols-in-hmisclatex) about applying latexTranslate with apply function, but this requires characters so I would have to unclass from factor to character.

I found another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694009/sexpr-special-latex-characters-etc-in-rnw-file?lq=1) that identifies the `knitr:::escape_latex` function however, the chunk then outputs the stuff as markup instead of translating it (using results='asis') or produces an R style table inside a code block (using results='markup'). I tried configuring it as a hook function in my parent document and it had the effect of outputting all the document contents as markup.  This is a brand new area for me so I probably implemented it incorrectly.

```
<<setup,include=FALSE>>=
hook_inline = knit_hooks$get('inline')
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  if (is.character(x)) x = knitr:::escape_latex(x)
  hook_inline(x)
})
@
...
<<tab-example,echo=FALSE,cache=TRUE,results='asis',sanitize=TRUE,inline=TRUE>>=
library("Hmisc")
library("memisc")
    example<-data.frame(cbind(x=1:100,y=1:100))
    example$x<-cut2(example$x,m=20)
    toLatex(example)
@
```

*According to @yihui this is the wrong way to go*

**UPDATE 2**

I have created a gsub wrapper which will escape percentages etc, however the [ symbol still pushes latex into maths mode and errors.

Comment: what is `cut2()`? I do not see `memisc::toLatex` either; there is only `utils::toLatex`

Comment: cut2 is a more versatile cut function provided in the Hmisc package.  In memisc, the toLatex function is greatly extended with a number of methods/classes to make it applicable in more situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of folks on the tex SE, a [ directly after a line break(\\) is considered an entry into math-mode.  It is very simple to prevent this behaviour by adding `{}` into the output just before a `[`.  My function looks like:

```
escapedLatex<-function (df = NULL) 
{
    require("memisc")
    gsub(gsub(x = toLatex(df, show.xvar = TRUE), pattern = "%", 
        replacement = "\\%", fixed = TRUE), pattern = "[", replacement = "{}[", 
        fixed = TRUE)
}
```

I'd be very happy to see any alternative, more elegant solutions around and will leave it open for a few days.

Comment: Using `[` after ``\\`` doesn't "enter math mode". It's because ``\\`` is a control sequence (or macro) that can have an optional argument, which is supplied using square brackets `[..]`. You avoid this supposition of an argument by inserting something (like `{}`) to trick LaTeX into thinking that there's no optional argument following ``\\``.